# Update google slide while presenting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

I need a Google slide in presentation mode and at the same time need to edit the slides with linked google sheet, and the editted content  must be updated in the presentation at real time itself. is it possible, or any other method or applications available for this purpose.

Comment: I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking for a Google Slide chart to continuously update whenever edits are made to it's source data in the Google Sheet, you could create an onEdit trigger in the Google Sheet document that updates the Google Slide chart if the chart data source is edited.

**Steps needed:**

- Copy and paste the following code into your Google Sheet (where the chart data is located) script file.
- Run the `createSpreadsheetOnEditTrigger` function
- Update `[Enter Chart Data Source Range]` of the `chartDataSourceRange` variable to the data range of the embedded chart.
- In the variable `slide`, replace `[Enter Presentation ID]` and `[Enter Slide ID]` with the IDs from your Google Slide Doc.
- Update the `chart` variable reference as needed. Right now it's only looking for the first chart from that slide.

**Notes:**

- The Google Slide chart will update ~2 seconds after an edit is made.
- Any changes in the chart data source made by a formula won't update the chart.
- If you don't run the createSpreadsheetOnEditTrigger function, you'll receive a permissions error.

**Code:**

```
/**
 * Creates a trigger for when a spreadsheet is edited.
 * @see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable
 */
function createSpreadsheetOnEditTrigger() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onEdit_')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}

function onEdit_(e) {
  var editedRange = e.range;
  var chartDataSourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange([Enter Chart Data Source Range]);
  if(!doesRangeIntersect(editedRange, chartDataSourceRange)) return;

  var slide = SlidesApp.openById([Enter Presentation ID]).getSlideById([Enter Slide ID])
  var chart = slide.getSheetsCharts()[0]
  chart.refresh()
}

function doesRangeIntersect(range1, range2) {
  range1 = new Coordinates(range1);
  range2 = new Coordinates(range2);
  return (
    Overlaps(range1.x1, range1.x2, range2.x1, range2.x2) &&
    Overlaps(range1.y1, range1.y2, range2.y1, range2.y2)
  );

  function Coordinates(range) {
    var self = this;
    self.x1 = range.getColumn();
    self.y1 = range.getRow();
    self.x2 = range.getLastColumn();
    self.y2 = range.getLastRow();
  }

  function Overlaps(a, b, c, d) {
    return (
      (a >= c && a <= d) ||
      (b >= c && b <= d) ||
      (c >= a && c <= b) ||
      (d >= a && d <= b)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ivin, did this help?

Comment: ... does not seem to affect active slideshows (see the Title of the original question)
I'm starting to think that it is not possible to include "Live Charts" in presentations that update while presenting them :-/